# How to push multiple docker images with docker-compose to docker hub?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry, docker-push

I have several images and services in my docker-compose file, For creating a PHP, Apache, MySql, and PHPMyAdmin environment to run my website. Can anyone help me with how can I push my all images or created an environment with my website code on Docker Hub?

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  phpmyadmin:
      image: phpmyadmin
      restart: always
      ports:
        - 8080:80
      environment:
         - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
```

index.php and all my website code in the **src** folder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's useful to understand what you can and can't push to Docker Hub.  Docker Hub will contain Docker images, but it can't host data content, the `docker-compose.yml` file itself, or anything else that's not a Docker image.  The two support containers you use both use standard Docker Hub images.  So you need to make your `php` container self-contained, push that to Docker Hub, and manually copy the `docker-compose.yml` file to the place you'll run it.

**Remove dependencies on the local system.**  You don't generally want to copy the application source code in addition to copying Docker containers around.  In the `docker-compose.yml` file, remove the `volumes:` that mount local-system source code into the container, but replace that with a Dockerfile line that copies it into the image:

```
COPY ./src/ /var/www/html/
```

This won't be a live development environment, and that's okay.

**Name your Docker Hub images.**  You can have both a `build:` and an `image:` line in the `docker-compose.yml` file.  If you do, that specifies the name the image will be built with (rather than letting Compose pick it).  This should leave you with:

```yaml
services:
  php:
    build: .  # with default Dockerfile
    image: myname/myapp
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    # no volumes:
  db: # as above
  phpmyadmin: # as above
```

**Build and test.**  You should be able to take this setup; `docker-compose down -v` to clean up all the local artifacts; `docker-compose build` the image, and `docker-compose up` to start it all.  Do whatever manual testing you need, plus any automated end-to-end tests you've built.

**Push the image.**

```sh
docker-compose push php
```

**Run it somewhere else.**  You need the `docker-compose.yml` file, but not any of the other artifacts.  When you run `docker-compose up` on the other machine, it will pull any images it doesn't already have locally.  (If it's a private image, you may need to `docker login` there first.)

```sh
scp docker-compose.yml there:
ssh root@there docker-compose up -d
```

**Database content.**  Your `docker-compose.yml` file doesn't declare `volumes:` to store database data; this could result in data loss across restarts.  However, you also can't push these volumes to Docker Hub.  You can back up your database on the local system and restore it on the remote system; or you can run database migration and seeding scripts as part of your application's startup.  The data needs to be dealt with separately from the code (images) and deployment mechanics (Compose).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add multiple images to a repository, add specific tags to these images.

I followed the steps described in Docker doc and I pushed 6 images to my docker hub repository.
[Link to Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/create/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20add,the%20tag%20defaults%20to%20latest%20.).

First of all, view the list of all local images using cmd:

```
docker-compose images
```

Now re-tag these images. You can re-tag them with any specific name. Run these commands for each image.

```
docker tag php:tag hub-user/repo-name:php
docker tag mysql:tag hub-user/repo-name:db
docker tag phpmyadmin:tag hub-user/repo-name:phpmyadmin
```

Once you've re-tagged all images, now it's time to push them to docker hub.

```
docker push hub-user/repo-name:php
docker push hub-user/repo-name:db
docker push hub-user/repo-name:phpmyadmin
```

The images are then uploaded to your docker hub repository.